# Can you (how can you) use Web Workers in jqGrid's 'url' property?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, web-worker

In our project, we are using jqGrid  have a very long running POST ajax query that locks up the UI.

One possible solution was to try and use Web Workers but since the url: property is just that, a URL, is it even possible to use Web Workers?